# Coin tossing problem where three tails come in a row

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

The problem is if I want to toss a coin n times, what is the number of ways possible when three tails comes in a row?
For example if I toss a coin for 4 times, the number of ways where 3 tails come in row is 3 i.e. TTTT, TTTH, HTTT. I need a generalized explanation for this.

Comment: Suggestion for finding the answer on the internet. Work out the answer for $n=3,4,5,6,7$ (easy to do by hand) and look for the sequence at http://oeis.org.

Comment: Didn’t an almost identical question come up a day ago?

Answer (score 5):

This is a classical problem.

We instead count the complement: The number of ways to have it so that **no three tails are in a row**. Later we subtract from $2^n$, the total number of sequences. This we can do by recursion. Let $x_n$ be the number of sequences of $n$ flips without TTT. For $n=0,1,2$, our answer is $1,2,4$, respectively.

If $n\geq 3$, note that the sequence ends with one of H, HT, HTT, since the last H must be one of the last 3 flips, or else the last 3 flips are all tails, which is not allowed.

Furthermore, appending H, HT, or HTT to a valid sequence produces another valid sequence. So, if it ends with H, there are $x_{n-1}$ ways to pick the first $n-1$ flips; if it ends with HT, there are $x_{n-2}$ possibilities for the first $n-2$ flips; and if it ends with HTT, we have $x_{n-3}$ choices.

Hence, $$\boxed{x_n = x_{n-1}+x_{n-2}+x_{n-3}}.$$ You can now use this to generate $x_n$ for any value of $n$, and take $2^n-x_n$ to compute the answer to your question.

Unfortunately, closed forms of this are weird, since in order to solve the recurrence we need the [roots of the characteristic polynomial](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=X%5E3%20%3D%20X%5E2%2BX%2B1), which are quite disgusting in this case.

Comment: But (n-1)*2^(n-4) this formula works for n>3. Could you please explain this?

Comment: Unfortunately that is not true, although promising; for $n=7$, the answer is 47.